# can i use OLTP tables as dimensional tables?

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I am still confused about the difference between the tables used in OLTP vs dimensional tables. Right now I am able to create a dashboard using OLTP tables by creating queries to aggregate info. Does that mean that my table is also a dimensional table?

Comment: A dimensional data model and 3NR model may store exactly the same set of data. It is technically possible to build reporting solutions on top of OLTP databases. However, it is strongly discouraged. The resulting queries will be overly complex, reports - slow and additionally the performance of the OLTP will be degraded.

Comment: thanks Marek for the explanation. It helped a lot.